# How to export to dxf file without the geometry having a triangular mesh?

Tags: mesh, export, faces, file-format

I have a simple 3D model made in Blender that I need to **export to AutoCAD** in **dxf** format. In Blender I have dissolved faces to simplify the geometry of the mesh.
When I export my model to dxf I get new triangles on the faces. My client asks me to eliminate this triangulation and make the mesh as clear as possible so that it can be edited in AutoCAD.
Is there a way to export my model in Blender **without creating those triangles**? Is it possible to export my model in Blender to another format that can open AutoCAD avoiding that triangular mesh? Is the methodology I am applying correct or is there a better one?
Please note that I will need to create many 3D models like the one I show in the image and that my client requests that the final file be in dxf or dwg.

[image: Triangular mesh when opening dxf in AutoCAD]

Comment: For all intents and purposes, if anyone's looking for an export solution, I've been developing a dxf exporter for my own needs, you can find it here : https://github.com/Gorgious56/blender_ezdxf_exporter/blob/main/README.md (free)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the DXF exporter always triangulates faces before exporting. I would suggest using .fbx as format instead, which [can be imported by AutoCAD](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/learn-explore/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/What-file-formats-can-AutoCAD-import.html).

Comment: Currently the .dxf exporter doesn't seem well maintained. The code is littered with commented code and to-do notes.

Comment: Thanks @rjgs, I will export my models to fbx files.
I see it's the best workflow for my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete all faces on your mesh in *Edit Mode* with <kbd>A</kbd>; <kbd>X</kbd> *Delete > Only Faces*) in Blender, and after export you will not have triangulation edges.

Answer (score -1):

With version 2.79 the DXF export exports well "without triangulation".

[image: dxf export]